# Highcharts - Json display an error message in place of the chart

Tags: json, highcharts

I am working on a script that send two dates to a query and in turn sends the result to a script that produces a chart (HighCharts).
If the query result is 0 (zero) I need to display a error message in place of the chart.

my chart script is:

```
$.getJSON("../charts/1-2-4-detractors_month_chart.php?From=<?php echo $StartDate;?>&To=<?php echo $EndDate;?>", function(json) { 
$.each(json,function(i,el) {
if (el.name=="Month")
   categories = el.data;
   else data2.push(el);
});

// followed by all the other chart formatting
```

If the Json result = null, how would I display a error message in place of the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts provide handling for no data. You need to add highcharts module called `no-data-to-display.js` after `highcharts.js` loaded

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData

& To customize error message
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/noData/lang.noData

Comment: example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/no-data-to-display/no-data-pie/)

Comment: I was not aware there was a function. I have it working. Many thanks for your help.